# From SPSS, import data from SQL Server Analysis Services

Tags: odbc, oledb, ssas, spss

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to load data from analysis services (SSAS) into SPSS.

SPSS offers a product to put SPSS functionality on the analysis server, but to me this is backwards.  I don't want to learn about SPSS or have the SPSS users in the office learn something else.

I just want to give the analysis services data to the SPSS users in SPSS.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better just to point SSPS at the relational datasource that SSAS is using. SSAS is not designed for doing bulk exporting of data. Evne if we did figure out a series of queries it would be many times slower than just querying the original source.

Answer (score 0):

SSAS has actions. You can fire an action which calls VB.net or c# code to format and import data into SPSS.